# I am using river-couchdb with ElasticSearch and would like to reset its last_seq to 0. Anybody know if that's possible?

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I am using this a plugin with elasticSearch called river-couchdb to create a full text index of my couchdb. It uses the couchdb _changes api to listen for documents. I assume it is keeping track of the last seq from the _changes api.

Sometimes we rebuild our CouchDB and set our last-seq back to 0. Only way I've found to reset the river-couchdb seq is to delete both its index and the river itself and recreate it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, you have a _seq document in your _river index for your river.
This document has a _last_seq entry.

If you want to restart from scratch, I think you can simply delete this document:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river/yourrivername/_seq
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

From couchdb-river manual:
[starting-at-a-specific-sequence](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb#starting-at-a-specific-sequence)

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river/yourrivername/_seq

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/yourrivername/_seq' -d '
{
  "couchdb": {
    "last_seq": "100"
  }
}'
```

Elasticsearch cant update last_seq without deleting old document